# How to insert a string value into a dialog message?

Tags: android, database, android-edittext

I have a editText and a button, if i type "abc" and hit the button it will store the value in my database and will open a dielog box saying it got insert successfully but in the dialog box i also want to show what got insert, so heres the code:

```
EditText texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
final String resultado = texto.getText().toString();

Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //Abre ou Cria uma database com nome de: "dbtest.db"
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("dbtest.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            try {
                db.insert("usuarioorigem", resultado, null);
                ShowMessage("Mensagens","Inserido" +resultado+ "com sucesso!");
            } finally {

            }
        } finally {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: whats the problem now? it should work. Whats the output now?

Comment: Put the errors in you post please. It will help us identifying issues.

Comment: the only "error" it gives is when i click the button and the dialog box come up the value of "resultado" doesnt show.

Comment: take this line "String resultado = texto.getText().toString();" inside of onClick(). Try and tell us the result.

Comment: The problem here is that resultado is not updated with the string that you input in EditText. You need to read it fresh on Onclick.

Comment: I have modified my answer based on above 2 comments. Try that code.

Comment: You should mark the answer given by me as correct. If that solved your problem. And upvote newbyca's answer as the showmessage method is from there.

Comment: @AlexandreF Yeah sorry if I was unclear. VendettaDroid provided the relevant answer.

Comment: Thanks newbyca for the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to check for the success of [insert operation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

```
   EditText texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);

            Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        //Abre ou Cria uma database com nome de: "dbtest.db"
                        db = openOrCreateDatabase("dbtest.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        String resultado = texto.getText().toString();

                        try{
                            long result = db.insert("usuarioorigem", resultado, null);
                            if(result == -1){
                               ShowMessage("Error in Insert"); //sorry for english here, may be u can use inserido
                            }
                            else{
                               ShowMessage("Mensagens Inserido" +resultado+ "com sucesso!");
                            }
                        }finally{

                        }
                }finally{

                }
                }
            });


    private void ShowMessage(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your ShowMessage function could look like this:

```
private void ShowMessage(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

See here for more info on [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Comment: Look at VendettaDroid's answer ... your problem isn't showing messages as much as its getting the text and handling your database insert correctly. Also note that be borrowed my ShowMessage function if\when you upvote his answer :)

Comment: You should mark the answer given by me as correct. If that solved your problem. And upvote newbyca's answer as the showmessage method is from there.

Comment: @AlexandreF Yeah sorry if I was unclear. VendettaDroid provided the relevant answer.

Comment: Thanks newbyca for the support. Upvote for the sportsman spirit and the method that I stole from you.