# How to show specific sqlite column value with text view + button?

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288038/how-to-insert-a-string-value-into-a-dialog-message) is how i have inserted the data into my database, so now i want to know how do i make a button that edit the textview values to the values of my database column.

Comment: Basically you want to edit the values already inserted into database and have a button for it? am I correct?

Comment: no, i want to edit the TEXTVIEW text as the values that the column in the database have it and have a button for it.

Comment: It makes it more clear. One more question, it means you want to update the TextView from the values stored in database? Am I correct? Sorry but I need this clarification.

Comment: YES, but not only one values stored in the database, all of them

Comment: I understand. How many values are expected from database? I am asking because. You can really utilise ListView here to display all the data from database.

Comment: Do you have any code at all running a query to the database? I wouldn't piece together an application with StackOverflow answers, there are different ways of doing it. I have a `DatabaseControl` class and a `DatabaseHelper` class that do all of the insertion and extracting for me. [Check out this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper), to extract you'll be using a `Cursor`

Comment: around 5 to 10 values and i dont know how to use the listView.
@Asok but im doing a simple app just to do some tests and remember stuff because im a beginner so im trying to learn this way and welL, simpler better

Comment: I have posted some code to help you get started. But You should really go through some basic example code given in Android as a part of APIDemos. This examples teach all the basic things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is the code to help you on database and Listactivity

```
public class MyDB { 
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private MyDBhelper mDbHelper;
public MyDB(Context context){   
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new MyDBhelper(mContext);
}

public MyDB createDatabase() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public MyDB open() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } 
    catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return this;
}


    public Cursor getplaces() 
    {
        Cursor c = mDb.query(Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return c;

    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

and for activity displaying list

```
public ListplaceActivity extends ListActivity {



    private static MyDB mDbHelper;
    String[] from = new String[] { Constants.TITLE_NAME };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.place_title};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mDbHelper = new MyDB(this);
        mDBHelper.open();
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.getplaces();
        setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, 
                  from, to));

}
```

Comment: ok, should i edit some code ? or just place it in my app, and my button and textview what it should be them "id" ?

Comment: You must edit the code based on your need. This is just the example.